# Tezos compiling storage using file

Tags: storage, compile

The Tezos documentation all show the storage expression being defined inline when compiling storage.  For example, using cameligo:

```
ligo compile storage src/counter.mligo 5 --entry-point main
```

If I try to put the expression '5' in a file, like initStorage.mligo, then using the file name instead, this does not seem to work.

Is it possible to define the initial storage in a file then compile storage with that file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard shell command substitution operators `` ` ` `` or `$()`:

`ligo compile storage src/counter.mligo "$(cat initStorage.mligo)" --entry-point main`